# GraphQL - operating elements of array

Tags: json, graphql, axios

I would like to display some information about members, but I don't know how to resolve array of field 'time'. This is array, because it shows their login time. What should I do? 
I used GraphQLString, but I am aware of this bad solution.

So I'm getting an error:

```
"message": "String cannot represent value: [\"12:08\"]",
```

Here is schema.js

```
const axios = require("axios");

const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLSchema
} = require("graphql");

const memberType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Member",
  fields: () => ({
    nick: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    name_and_surname: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    time: {
      type: GraphQLString
    }
  })
});


//Root Query
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootQueryType",
  fields: {
    users: {
      type: new GraphQLList(memberType),
      description: "List of members",
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return axios
          .get("http://25.98.140.121:5000/data")
          .then(res => res.data);
      }
    }
  }
})

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootQuery
});
```

And here is JSON

```
[
    {
        "time": [
            "12:08"
        ],
        "nick": "Cogi12",
        "name_and_surname: "John Steps"
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "12:16"
        ],
        "nick": "haris22",
        "name_and_surname": "Kenny Jobs"
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "12:07",
            "12:08",
            "12:17",
            "12:19",
            "12:45",           
            "13:25"
        ],
        "nick": "Wonski",
        "name_and_surname": "Mathew Oxford"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `GraphQLList` along with `GraphQLString` for `time` type like this,

```
const memberType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Member",
  fields: () => ({
    nick: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    name_and_surname: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    time: {
      type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString)
    }
  })
});
```